# Unpacking software for analysis

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

Has anyone ever tried to analyze binaries for radmin..
I was just trying to analyze it for getting a hands on experience. I found out that it is somehow packed or encrypted. I mean a very few imports with getprocaddress, loadlibrary, virtualalloc being some calls among them..IDA does not recognize much..processexplorer shows the process in violet..but all the sections are there.

there were also some other things I saw during debugging the radmin process like:-
crashing ollydbg, generating exceptions and getting terminated, getting terminated in the debugger and when I close the attached debugger, the process remains alive and works as it should..totally weird..

Can anyone suggest how I should go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find out with which obfuscator the images have been scrambled? You could try with [PEID](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/PEiD-updated.shtml).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. but PEiD shows it as visual c++ compiler..but I am pretty sure its somehow packed or encrypted as well..Btw none of the automatic detection tools were able to tell it as packed based on signature detection..so I am guessing proprietary packing or encryption..

Comment: just tried it on PeStudio (http://www.winitor.com). Image is definitively encrypted (4 Sections - .Sec0 -> .Sec3) are RWE.

Comment: "H.J. Lu - PATCH" seems to be related to these sections.

Comment: sorry didn't got u there? "H.J. LU -PATCH" is that a packer or crypter..and what is RWE..sorry I am a beginner :)

Comment: I got to "H.J. LU -PATCH" using google :-). Seems to be a packer. and RWE actually stands for rwe (Read Write Execute). Sections that are Executable AND Writable are first candidates for obfuscation detection.

Comment: ohh :) got it..btw u r doing the analysis on rserver30.exe right?

Comment: both rserver30.exe and rasadmin.exe are apparently encrypted using the same engine. And both have had apparently the same original name "prot_run.exe".

Comment: I used PeStudio! And spent thousands of hour reading the Microsoft Portable Executable Specification (PE) and researches on PE.

Comment: Hey nice..just used that and got all that info..anything we can do about decrypting this?

Comment: find the engine reversing the cryptor...:-( Or being successful against the anti-debugging mechanisms.

Comment: hehe okk :) sounds difficult :| but fun

Comment: H. J. Lu is a software engineer at Intel. He does indeed write a lot of patches for the linux kernel, which is totally unrelated in any way to this question.

Comment: @drhirsch thanks , I read that on google..so u have any ideas on how to solve the problem of unpacking this proprietary encryption..any other ways than understanding the algo and undo that?